# Using react hook forms with dynamically added components

Tags: reactjs

I have some components with the same set of input fields. User could add them or remove them.

```
    const [sectionItems, setActionItems] = useState<ISectionItems[]>([
    {id: Date.now(), number: 1}
])

    {sectionItems.map((sectionItem) =>
    <SectionItem
        key={sectionItem.id}
        number={sectionItem.number}
        addSectionItem={addSectionItem}
        removeSectionItem={removeSectionItem}
        isOnlySection={isOnlySection}
    />)}
```

So the fiels are inside each SectionItem component.

I use react-hook-forms to get the data from the form, but I have no idea how to deal with that in the situation when we have dynamically changing list of components

```
const SectionItem: FC<SectionItemProps> = (SectionItemProps) => {

const addClickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    SectionItemProps.addSectionItem()
}

const removeClickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    SectionItemProps.removeSectionItem(SectionItemProps.number)
}


return (
    <React.Fragment>
  <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom sx={{marginTop: 3}}>
            {`Участок № ${SectionItemProps.number}`}
  </Typography>
        <Grid container spacing={3} sx={{marginTop: 1}}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="insideDiameter"
                    name="insideDiameter"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="standard"
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="outsideDiameter"
                    name="outsideDiameter"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="standard"
                />
            </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={3} sx={{marginTop: 1}}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <Fab size="small" aria-label="add" >
                    <AddIcon color = 'primary' onClick={addClickHandler}/>
                </Fab>
                {SectionItemProps.isOnlySection
                    ?   <></>
                    : <Fab size="small" aria-label="add" sx={{marginLeft: 1}}>
                            <RemoveIcon color='primary' onClick={removeClickHandler} />
                        </Fab>
                }
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: i think you should see https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray

Comment: Yes, official documentations provides some examples for dynamically adding fields. But it's unclear what to do with dynamically adding components. I stuck with the interpretation for such case

Comment: Hi @Ivan, can you provide more details of your goal, what your problem is and your expectation. I am struggling to understand your goal.

Comment: The thing is that I have a form with a set of fields in the component (SectionItem). User could add as many SectionItem-component as he need via click on a button. So, I initially I render one SectionItem-component, but users could add more SectionItems if they need. To acheve such behaviour I have a list of SectionItem components and I render them using a map function. To get form data I use Reack-hook-forms, and to validate form values I use Yop. The problems is I do not undertand how to use react-hook-forms if I need get the data from all the SectionItem components

Answer (score 0):

getValues from useForm should let you access the values. setValue from useForm should also cause a render. watch is another one like getValues except it causes a render as well and is useful for dynamically changing the form.

```
            <FormControl
              display="flex"
              alignItems="center"
              justifyContent={"flex-end"}
              gap={"4"}
              h={"12"}
            >
              <Switch
                id="email-alerts"
                {...register("isInstructor")}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  console.log(getValues("isInstructor") ? "1" : "2");
                  setValue("isInstructor", !getValues("isInstructor"));
                }}
              />
              <FormLabel htmlFor="email-alerts" mb="0">
                معلم
              </FormLabel>
            </FormControl>
```

In this example, the instructor toggle for me needs to add different input fields to the form. Using setValue causes a render and watch lets me access it and make it dynamic in other parts of the form not mentioned here.

I don't have experience with field arrays in hook forms but if they are like Formik field arrays then your use case and anyone else reading this is good to go.